# Segmentation Fault in Hash Table - C

Tags: c, struct, memory-leaks, segmentation-fault, hashtable

I am currently working on a programming assignment for class. I am getting a seg fault in one of my functions and can not come to the root of the issue. I have done my best and found that the seg fault occurs in "if(myNode->key==key)". Any wise words will help!

```
struct node*searchForPerson(const char *value){
int key=convertToKey(value);
struct node *myNode;

int i=0;
int j = (key % 8)+(i*(key%5));


while (i < size - 1 && hashTable[j].head != NULL && hashTable[j].index != key ) {
    i++;
    j=(key % 8)+(i*(key%5));
}
myNode=hashTable[j].head;

if(myNode->key==key) {

    printf(" found\n");
    return myNode;
}
else{
printf("not found\n");
    return NULL;
    }
}
```

I thought that the root of the issue may be my insert to hash function:

```
void insertToHash(int key,  char *value){

int i = 0;
int j = (key % 8)+(i*(key%5));
struct node *newnode = createNode(key, value);
/*head of list for the bucket with index "hashIndex"*/
if (!hashTable[j].head) {
    hashTable[j].head = newnode;
    hashTable[j].count=1;
    return;
}

while (i < size - 1 && hashTable[j].head != NULL) {
    i++;
    j=(key % 8)+(i*(key%5));
}
//adding new node to the list
hashTable[j].head=newnode;
hashTable[j].count++;
return;



hashTable[j].head = newnode;
hashTable[j].count++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add an if statement which ensures that `hashTable[j].head` is not `NULL`.

Keep in mind that your while loop condition is ANDing 3 conditions, so if **any one of them** becomes false, the loop will exit. In particular, immediately after your loop you don't know if it exited because

1. `i` is now greater than or equal to `size - 1`
2. `hashTable[j].head` is now equal to `NULL`
3. `hashTable[j].index` is now equal to `key`

If the case is (2), then `myNode` will be `NULL` so `myNode->key` will be dereferencing a null pointer, resulting in a segfault.

Comment: Do you mean implement the if statement in the search function?

Comment: Yes, before you say `myNode = hashTable[j].head`

Comment: I added the if before the statement and found that hashtable head was indeed equal to null. So I was dereferencing a null pointer. I'm not sure how to fix it entirely but I will try to modify my while loop, thank you!